# Can I highlight interactive objects?

Tags: diablo-iii

With the <kbd>ALT</kbd> key, I can highlight phat lewt that is scattered about.  However, this doesn't highlight other interactive objects, such as barrels or other objects that can be destroyed/looted.

Is there some way to highlight these objects without just sweeping my mouse over them?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Nope - but missing one is not a big issue at all. Important things (including lore book containers) are sparkling/glowing anyway.